# "unable to get local issuer certificate"

Tags: yarnpkg

```
 [builder 4/6] RUN yarn:
#10 0.574 yarn install v1.22.19
#10 0.704 [1/4] Resolving packages...
#10 1.587 [2/4] Fetching packages...
#10 2.112 error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@babel/runtime/-/runtime-7.18.9.tgz: unable to get local issuer certificate".
#10 2.112 info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/app/yarn-error.log".
#10 2.112 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yarn]: exit code: 1
```

I have used the following commands, but still, I'm getting this error certificate error.

```
yarn install --ignore-engines --ignore-platform
yarn config set "strict-ssl" false -g
yarn config set enableStrictSsl false
```